# Requisição com Axios e React bloqueada por política CORS

Tags: react, cors, axios

Estou tentando fazer a requisição para uma API, usando Axios:

```
  axios.post('http://api.teste.com.br/v1/getToken', {
      withCredentials: true,
      auth: {
          username: 'usuario',
          password: 'password'
      },
      headers: {                  
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Authorization", 
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE" ,
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"                   
      },
  }).then(resp => {  
    console.log(resp)
  })
  .catch(error => {          
      console.log(error)       
  })
```

Mas sempre apresenta o erro:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.teste.com.br/v1/getToken' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Existe alguma configuração a mais para fazer? Lembrando que é uma API de terceiros e eu não posso alterar o CORS no servidor, e no PostMan funciona sem problemas.

Comment: Você está chamando `axios.post()`, não seria `axios.get()`?

Comment: Eu também achei estranho mais esta como post na documentação da API.

Comment: Provavelmente a API não aceita o valor informado no "Content-Type".

Comment: Sua api é em que?

Comment: a api é de terceiros, não sei qual a linguagem ela foi desenvolvida. Mais no postman eu passo o "Content-Type" como application/json e funciona.

Comment: O problema é que o CORS bloqueia da forma que vc ta fazendo

Comment: Isso mesmo o problema é o CORS. Eu achei a solução aqui : https://medium.com/@gigioSouza/resolvendo-o-problema-do-cors-com-angular-2-e-o-angular-cli-7f7cb7aab3c2

Comment: Instala esse plugin no crome: [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi), de vez em quando preciso habilitar ele pra funcionar em minhas aplicações localmente quando faço consultas ao ViaCep

Comment: Tenta alterar o `Content-type` para `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` e veja se muda algo. Referências: [Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30554385/8133067) e [differences in application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880122/8133067).

Comment: Certo, mas o problema é que quando você roda npm run build, o proxy é ignorado, e você volta a ter o mesmo problema. Até então não consegue achar uma solução para isto, você conseguiu?

Comment: Eu achei estranho porque a resposta do erro é que não suporta o Content-Type que você passou.

Answer (score 4):

Tive o mesmo problema com uma API de terceiros. Demorei para pensar mais é simples. Você só pode acessar a api no Back-end. Se for no front-end dá erro. No seu WebService acesse a API de terceiros. Adicionei o CORS para autorizar.

Exemplo para criar uma API em Node.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

app.listen(3333)

app.use(cors())
app.get('/sms', (req,res)=>{   
     
    axios.post('https://apideterceiros/api',{    
        
            user: '1234',
            contact: [
              {
                number: '534543543',
                message: 'test message 1',
                externalid: '123456'
              }
            ],
            type: '2'      
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log(response.headers)
        console.log(response.status)
    }).catch(function(error){
        if(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
    
    return res.json({teste:1})
})
```

Comment: Estava com o mesmo problema e usei a lib "cors" e deu certinho, valeu !

Comment: Coloca como resposta. rsrsrsrs

Answer (score 2):

O que aconteceu foi o seguinte:

1. A aplicação tentou fazer uma requisição POST para um server com outro hostname.
2. O browser identificou o método POST para outro host; de acordo com a especificação, isso significa que é uma requisição CORS que precisa de um pre-flight request.
3. O browser fez o pre-flight request, que é uma requisição OPTION que verifica se o request original será aceito pelo server, mandando os headers desse request original assim como definidos no código da pergunta (ps: os headers Access-Control-* é respondido pelo server, o client não precisa enviá-los).
4. O server recebeu o pre-flight e respondeu com os Headers que ele aceita.
5. O browser identificou na resposta que o request original não será permitido, pois o Header Content-Type não estava entre os aceitos e crashou antes de fazê-lo.

A solução para esse problema é verificar a documentação da api que você está utilizando para verificar os headers. Creio que por ser uma requisição que usa HTTP Authentication, não precisa enviar o Content-Type application/json.

Não se esqueça de remover os headers Access-Control-*. Esses headers são respondidos pelo server para atender a especificação do CORS.

Se quiser mais detalhes sobre o funcionamento do CORS, essa [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) da Mozilla é muito boa.

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde!

Problema solucionando. Eu criei um proxy no arquivo package.json

`"proxy": "http://api.teste.com.br/v1"` e fiz a requisição assim:

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:3000/getToken',  {username : "user", password : "password"})
  .then(resp => {  
      console.log(resp.data.data.authorization)
  })
  .catch(error => {          
      console.log(error)       
  })
```

Desta maneira o proxy meio que engana o CORS e não tem mais problemas.

Answer (score -2):

Tive o mesmo problema, no fim é só usar a lib [https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Bem simples de implementar e vai resolver seu problema, cuidado apenas no ambiente de produção para não deixar tudo liberado, com essa lib você pode liberar tudo ou algumas coisas apenas, vale a pena dar uma lida nela.

Espero ter ajudado quem chegou até aqui.