# Requisição bloqueada pelo CORS - Vue e Spring Boot

Tags: vue.js, spring-boot, cors, axios

Tenho uma API Spring Boot e uma aplicação Vue, ambos rodando locais, porém não consigo fazer uma requisição PUT da aplicação Vue para API. Se mandar uma requisição GET, funciona perfeitamente. Tentei, inclusive criar um proxy como mostrado aui: [Requisição com Axios e React bloqueada por política CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349565/requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-com-axios-e-react-bloqueada-por-pol%c3%adtica-cors). Mas sem sucesso.

O erro que recebo no navegador é o seguinte:

[image: Erro vue]

Já habilitei a anotação no minha resource na API e desabilitei o cors na configuração do security também:
Resource:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/curso")
public class CursoResource {

    @Autowired
    CursoService cursoService;

    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Curso curso){
        curso.setId(id);
        cursoService.updateCurso(curso);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
```

Security config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
                //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, PUBLIC_MATCHERS_GET).permitAll()
                //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ADMIN_MATCHERS_POST).hasAuthority("ADMIN");
                //.anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil));
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil, userDetailsService));
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

Tento fazer a requisição com axios:

```
axios.put('http://localhost:8082/curso/' + this.cursoid, this.curso).
            then((response) => {
                alert('Disciplina adicionada!')
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente realizar esta classe de configuração para ajustar os headers do CORS:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        configSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return configSource;
    }
}
```

Talvez seja a única configuração faltante, você pode conferir pela [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html)