# Requisição está apresentando Cross-Origin Request Blocked em app Reactjs

Tags: node.js, react, express.js, cors, axios

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em React e anteriormente criei uma API restful com node e o express, em minha api eu adicionei o modulo cors `const cors = require('cors');` e o adicionei na inicialização do mesmo para que seja permitidas as requisições, ate ai tudo certo, o problema e quando eu passo para a aplicação react, onde também adicionei o modulo axios `const axios = require("axios");` para tratar as requisições feitas pela aplicação e assim evitar o Cross-Origin mas mesmo assim ele me retorna o bloqueio do mesmo.
Quando faço uma consulta em outra API a aplicação consegue me trazer os dados, não sei se o motivo e devido os dois estarem rodando na mesma  maquina.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos que puderem me ajudar! :)

**Trecho Reactjs**

```
 axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/MarcodeContainers").then(function (resposta) {

        var teste = resposta.data;

        console.log(teste);

    });
```

**Trecho De inicialização express nodejs**

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const webServerConfig = require('../config/web-server.js');
const router = require('./router');
const cors = require('cors');

let httpServer;
function initialize() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());

    httpServer = http.createServer(app);

    app.use(morgan('combined'));
    app.use(express.json({
        reviver: reviveJson
    }));

    app.use('/api', router);

    httpServer.listen(webServerConfig.port)
        .on('listening', () => {
            console.log(`Web server ouvindo em localhost:${webServerConfig.port}`);

            resolve();
        })
        .on('error', err => {
            reject(err);
        });
});
}
```

Comment: Adicione `crossdomain: true` no axios. Ex `axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/MarcodeContainers", {crossdomain: true})`;

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta JustCase, mas infelizmente não funcionou!

Comment: O que você tem no arquivo router?

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos com suas respostas, mas aparentemente consegui achar a solução, em uma pergunta aqui no stack.
segue o link [Requisição com Axios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349565/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-axios-e-react-bloqueada-por-pol%C3%ADtica-cors#_=_)

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:3001/api",
```

Adicionei a linha de codigo acima no meu package.json e funcionou corretamente ,realizou a requisição sem apresentar a mensagem de CROS. Espero que continue assim após realizar alguma atualização de modulos.